# should i using System.Windows.Forms in the Presenter class base on MVP

Tags: design-patterns, mvp

In the article [Build your own CAB Part #8 - Assigning Responsibilities in a Model View Presenter Architecture](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2007/06/10/build-your-own-cab-part-8-model-view-presenter-wrapup.aspx), the author said:

> but don't allow any reference to any
>   Type in the System.Windows.Forms
>   namespace from the Presenter class.

---

I have some questions for your above words. Suppose I want to build a tree in the UI, and for each tree node I need attach some info, so the IView should expose a interface AddTreeNode to Presenter, so the Presenter can call this interface to add a treenode on the tree, right? I think the parameters for AddTreeNode interface should be like (TreeNode newNode, TreeNode Parent), then in the Presenter class it should add System.Windows.Forms as reference, how should I handle this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the IView should expose a interface AddTreeNode to Presenter

Not really. I think that IView should expose events which Presenter can call to pass model data there. View layer  implements those events and can take the data and call any methods of controls (AddTreeNode and so on).

Comment: suppose there is an event RefreshTheTree exposed by TestView which implements the IView interface, then in the Presenter it subscribe this event, and in the event handle method, it get data from the Model, then what should I do to add the treenode according to the data from Model?

Comment: @Carlos_Liu there are many ways. f.e. you may define a method in IView  addNode(modelNode node) and call it in Presenter. so that TestView will take modelNode and add treenode inside this method. So all access to UI controls are allowed in TestView only. modelnode is a Model entity which carries info you want to add as tree node. So again you don't need to expose UI info out of TestView class.